# compile ffmpeg centos

Tags: centos, root, ffmpeg

I used this Guide http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos
To install ffmpeg in my VPS with CentOS 6 64.
But it was installed in `/root/bin/` and I need to install it in `usr/bin/`
to run without Permission denied like this http://discourse.clipbucket.com/t/problem-in-video-converter-2-7/135

Comment: If you're trying to call `ffmpeg` from a web script, you should probably disable SELinux or set it to allow the execution with `audit2allow`.

Comment: Also, can you edit your post to include the commands you used to compile and install the program?

Comment: @Bratchley I used all the commands in this Guide http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

Comment: Don't specify the `--prefix` or `--bindir` options to the configure. That's telling it to install to your home directory instead of the default location.

Comment: Basically, be wary of any of those commands that contain `$HOME`

Comment: BTW is there a reason you're compiling from source instead of using [the RPM fusion repo](http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/6/x86_64/repoview/ffmpeg.html)? If that version of `ffmpeg` is alright it seems like that would be easier to install.

Comment: Bratcheley is right, you should have used the --prefix. You can try symlinking over to /usr/bin. With the right permissions that should work.

Comment: In CentOS 6.8, I used this Guide http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos To install ffmpeg.
Then just copy files: ffmpeg, ffprobe, ffserver, lame, vsyasm, x264, yasm, ytasm from "/root/bin" to "/usr/bin".
It works.